# Is "Yatogami" a name or a title?

Tags: noragami

In Noragami, the main character refers to himself as "yatogami". I'm not sure if that's his name or his title. A quick google search shows that its a surname, but the way he said it makes me think its some kind of title.

Comment: Well after seeing some episodes of the season two it seems to be true because the history of Yato-no-kami suits Yatogami very well.

Comment: Also, he killed "them" because not because "they" intruded his territory, but because someone requested to kill "them". Doesn't seem related to Yatou-no-kami at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Noragami, Yato refers to himself as a god. 神, which is the kanji for god, can be pronounced "gami", so he is probably referring to himself literally as "Yato God".

Comment: So then `Yatogami` is in fact an alias? @kuwaly

Answer (score 3):

His name in Kanji is 夜卜

> Yato is neither, but rather an alias. The 卜 is actually a kanji and not the katakana "to" that he makes people believe it is by calling himself Yato. His name is actually Yaboku.

Gami, one of the pronunciations of 神 would be his title, since it means god.